# Why isn't there a warning on identity assignment?

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

I've made this mistake a number of times - it happens when I'm working quickly and using code completion.  I end up with code like the following:

```
public class Model : IModel
{
    public PropertyNames PropertyNames { get; set; }
    public Model(PropertyNames propertyNames)
    {
        PropertyNames = PropertyNames;
    }
}
```

Then a test fails in a slightly less than obvious way, and I get bummed out.

I'm just curious if there's a valid reason to write code like that, ever, and if not, then does it make for a good candidate to generate a warning?

Comment: I agree that this behavior is pretty nutty. I feel like, at the very least, code completion should somehow be smarter.

Comment: On a side note I usually try to avoid a situation where I end up with a Property with the Same Name as it's type. e.g. `public PropertyNames Names { get; set; }`

Comment: You might want to read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/03/danger-will-robinson.aspx

Comment: @Eoin, i agree using the property name the same goes against my instinct too, but i started doing it when I noted more experienced developers doing it and over time I've judged it have a cumulative posative effect on overall complexity (ps. if we start debating on this the thread will get closed... :))

Comment: @Pegram, thanks for the reference - in his example, the error caused a stack overflow and thus the reasoning behind not causing a warning was "it would be caught right away" - i'm not complaining here but I had a case where the error was caught slightly less than right away.. my property had its default value (null i suppose) and things behaved as if initialization failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FxCop (aka Code Analysis), it will give you the warning:

Warning 3   CA1801 : Microsoft.Usage : Parameter 'propertyNames' of 'Model.Model(string)' is never used. Remove the parameter or use it in the method body.

Comment: i played a little loose with the rules voting this the answer because it was the most useful answer for me, even though taken literally it answers my problem not my question :) Hope thats ok.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm just curious if there's a valid reason to write code like that, ever

Depending on how you look at, unfortunately yes there is.  Because the identifier we are talking about is a property, assigning a property to a property **sounds** like a no-op but it actually invokes methods, the getter and the setter, and those methods might have side effects.

A specific case that is very common is if the setter does something like property notification or calls an observer but anything could happen when you call either the getter or the setter.  This is why the code does not generate a warning: because this coding style is actually useful and used in production code.

**Edit:**

By comparison, if the identifier is a *field* and not a *property*, it does generate this warning:

> warning CS1717: Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?

Comment: I appreciate your use of *unfortunately* here.

Comment: Btw, it would be great if this warning was generated when assigning to a read-only / auto property as well.

Answer (score 3):

Other than "it counts as a valid instruction", there's no reason to ever use this. That said, it's also not wrong: it conforms the syntax for assignment.

If you are writing a code validator, then this is a good candidate for a warning, although of course it should never hamper actual compiling; most compilers already catch this kind of operation during bytecode optimisation, where instructions that do not perform any control logic and don't actually modify registers are removed.

Comment: Off-topic... This type of property assignment isn't guaranteed to be a nop in the general case: The getter could trigger all kinds of side-effecting actions, and the class author could be using the `P = P` assignment as a (crazy, roundabout, error-prone) way of triggering those actions from the constructor.

Comment: @LukeH: Not off-topic, in fact that is what the question is.

Comment: @LukeH, your right of course - i'd only say that it reminded my brain of something that I think caused a warning from my c/c++ days, and the general class of warning it fell under was "if it's easy to write by mistake and 99% of the time it really IS a mistake, then generate a warning".. easiest thing I can think of is if you put an assignment in an expression, single = instead of ==... the language allows it but the developer rarely intends it.